# Self hosting a Subdomain of domain hosted on Azure dns

Tags: windows, azure, dns

I am hosting my domain `example.com` on Microsoft Azure dns. I am trying to host a subdomain `my.example.com` on my own server but failing to do it correctly. This is how it is.

1. I have installed a windows server (`s1.my.example.com`) with active directory and dns for `"my.example.com"`.
2. the server has one public ip `a.b.c.d` and one ip in private range i.e `10.x.y.z` range
3. I have created a ns record in Azure dns in the zone example.com 
   `my  NS 3600 a.b.c.d`
4. Now when I run `dig +trace s1.my.example.com` then I get a proper result with the two ip's.

   `s1.my.example.com.  1200    IN  A   a.b.c.d
   s1.my.example.com.  1200    IN  A   10.x.y.z`
5. But when I run dig s1.my.example.com a

```
 ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1 <<>> s1.my.example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 17291
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;s1.my.example.com.     IN  A

;; Query time: 146 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)"
```

When I provide dig with one of azure dns nameserver hosting my primary zone I get

```
dig s1.my.example.com @ns4-09.azure-dns.info.
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1 <<>> s1.my.example.com @ns4-09.azure-dns.info.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22604
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;s1.my.example.com.     IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
my.example.com. 3600    IN  NS  a.b.c.d.

;; Query time: 222 msec
;; SERVER: 13.107.160.9#53(13.107.160.9)
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you host a public domain `example.com` on Azure DNS? Could you check the `nslookup` result?

Comment: Yes I have the public domain hosted on Azure DNS and the `example.com` dns resolves correctly using `nslookup` while `s1.my.example.com` results a `Server fail`.

Comment: Could you try to set the ns record in Azure DNS in the zone example.com `my  NS 3600 vmfqdn`? [How to create fqdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn#create-a-fqdn)

Comment: If you don't host DNS zones in Azure DNS, instead you directly edit the NS record for the subdomain `my.example.com`, is this working? I try to edit NS records in my domain provider, this works.

Comment: I am hosting my zone `example.com` in Azure DNS but my subdomain machine is not being hosted on Azure platform. I am hosting the server `ds1.my.example.com` in my organization server room. And have created the `ns` record as I have created a ns record in Azure dns in the zone example.com my  NS 3600 public_ip_of_my_hosted_server.